# Error in defining a selfmade superclass with subclasses

Tags: java

I wrote an abstract superclass distribution as folows, it contains a constructor, and two methods.

```
public abstract class Distribution
{
 public Distribution(){}

 public abstract void setParameters(HashMap<String,?> hm);

 public abstract int getSample();
}
```

Hereafter, I wrote 4 subclasses ( Poisson, Geometric, Deterministic and Binomial ). These subclasses all look the same and are like this;

```
public class Binomial extends Distribution
{
    BinomialDistribution distribution;

   public Binomial()
   {
       super();
   }

    @Override
    public void setParameters(HashMap<String,?> hm)
    {
    try
    {
         int n = 0;
         double p =0.0;
            if (hm.containsKey("n"))
                if (hm.containsKey("p"))
                    p = Double.parseDouble((String) hm.get("p"));
                else 
                    throw new Exception("Exception: No p-value found");
            else
                throw new Exception("Exception: No n-value found");


        distribution = new BinomialDistribution(n,p);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    }


    @Override
    public int getSample()
   {
       return distribution.sample();

   }  

}
```

In another class I want to use these classes. I want to give a HashMap to the Distribution.setparameters method, and let the program decide which subclass that fits the parameters given in that HashMap.

If I want to define A distribution the other class, this doesn't seem to work.

```
Distribution arrivalLength1distr = new Distribution();
```

Can somebody tell me what I do wrong and how my problem could be solved ?

Thanks !

Comment: `Distribution` is `abstract`. You can't instantiate it. You need something like `Distribution arrivalLength1distr = new Binomial()`.

Comment: I don't quite get your question, mainly because I'm missing a description of the actual error you get as well as an example of how you'd intend to use it. I have the strong feeling though that you'll want to use a generic type for the map, e.g. `Map<String, T> hm` (note I used the interface instead of the implementation) and let the subclasses define what `T` actually is.

Comment: Upon reading your question a second time as well as bradimus' comment, it seems you'll want to look into factory methods (or the factory pattern in general), i.e. you'd then do something like `Distribution d = Distribution.create( valueMap );` and the `create(...)` method would analyze the map and create the appropriate instance of a subclass.

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem... but as there is no implementation to be inherited from `Distribution` it should rather be an interface instead of an abstract class.